Spring Boot Prometheus endpoint doesn't display metrics from global registry
Working on a project that uses Micrometer/Spring boot for tracking some metrics, e.g. JVM which works fine. Trying to add/track reactor netty metrics that use Micrometer's global registry. Spring Boot is auto-configured to setup Prometheus and metrics endpoints and it appears to be using a PrometheusRegistry for all JVM metrics. The /Prometheus endpoint only displays metrics that are stored in the Prometheus registry, none of the others that are stored in the global registry (netty reactor).
I can see the reactor HTTP metrics stored in the global registry just trying to figure out how to get them published via the /prometheus endpoint... I'm not sure if this is an issue with the endpoint not looking at the global registry or some other configuration of the Prometheus registry.
Enabled netty reactor provider pool metrics on the connection provider but none of the metrics are visible via the /Prometheus endpoint.
The metrics are attached to the global registry and I can see that /Prometheus pulls its metrics from only the Prometheus registry and seems to ignore the global registry.
